# Android unable to attach image to Facebook,Twitter,Email via my app.Please Suggest

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, android-assets

I am making a photo gallery app in which I try to load images from asset folder. I'm successful in doing this.

Now I want to share the image(single not multiple) via email, facebook and twitter.
This is where my problem starts.
I'm able to post a plain message via my app but I'm unable to post my image or attach my image with it.
I don't know how to do this. I tried many tutorials but to no help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload image first somewhere on the internet, so the Facebook can download it.

Answer (score 0):

here you go it works for me:

```
final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null){
// check publish permissions here
// if there is no permission request it and return;
//else if there is permission
logMessage("Has permission go on");
        final Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        if(File("yourImagePath").exists())
        {
            byte[] data = null;
                    File screenShotFile = new File("yourImagePath");
            logMessage("getting screenShot here");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(screenShotFile);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();  
            postParams.putByteArray("picture", data);

           logMessage("added pic as byte array to params");
        }
        postParams.putString("name", "Post name");
        postParams.putString("caption", "caption");
        postParams.putString("description", "desc");
        postParams.putString("link", "http://www....");
            final Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) 
            {
                FacebookRequestError error;
                try {
                    error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) 
                    {
                        makeToast(error.getErrorMessage());
                        logMessage(error.getErrorMessage());
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        // no errors so delete image here
                        if(screenShotFile != null)
                        {
                            screenShotFile.delete();
                            logMessage("deleted");
                            screenShotFile = null;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                logMessage(response.toString());
            }
        };
Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", postParams, 
                              HttpMethod.POST, callback);
                    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                    task.execute();
logMessage("made feed request check");
         }
```